# Getting the Word Count after splitting an URL into an array of words

Tags: sql, arrays, hive, hiveql, regexp-replace

I have a table with a list of URLs

```
url

http://03cubsml.baseball.cbssports.com/stats/stats-main?selectedplayer=2122997
http://08flb.baseball.cbssports.com/scoring/standard
http://100-poems.com/poems/life/index2.htm
http://10000lakesrbl.baseball.cbssports.com/stats/stats-main
http://1000pictures.com/view.htm?cscenic/sunset+fnoy-2011-07-21-211010+a1112212325323435434553545885949hh9
http://05command.wikidot.com/tech-hub-tag-list
http://10000lakesrbl.baseball.cbssports.com/players/playerpage/2504134
http://1001goroskop.ru/gadanie/?kniga-sudeb
http://04spfbl.baseball.cbssports.com/standings/overall
http://05command.wikidot.com
http://05command.wikidot.com/tech-hub-tag
http://05fbl.baseball.cbssports.com/stats/stats-main
http://100-poems.com/poems/life/0464004.htm
http://10000islands.proboards.com/board/129/tito-headquarters
http://10000islands.proboards.com/thread/11959/tip-islands-party?page=477
http://10000islands.proboards.com/thread/14172/illustrious-house-improving-wordiness?page=82
http://1000pictures.com/view.htm?cscenic/sunset+feilat05-040+a1112212325323435434553545885949hh9
http://1001-rimes.com/listeperson.php?letter=%E9&start=30
http://1001-rimes.com/listeperson.php?letter=ques&start=30
http://1001goroskop.ru/?god
```

I am now splitting the URLs to list of words present in the URL using the following code

```
Create table url_keyword
(url string,
keywords Array<String>);

Insert Overwrite table url_keyword
as
Select url,split(lcase (parse_url (url,'PATH')),"[=/_%:|^$#@!&,?*_~+.`<>(){}' \-\;\" \\ \\[\\]{[0 -9]+ }]") AS keywords from url_table;
```

The output i get has url and keywords(space seperated array) generated by splitting the array. Now i want to get a word count generated by each url but whenever i am trying to do a

```
regexp_replace(keywords,' ',',')
```

to convert it into an comma separated array so that i can use length function to get the word count, i get the error

```
Wrong arguments '','': No matching method for class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFRegExpReplace with (array, string, string). Possible choices: _FUNC_(string, string, string)
```

How can I achieve the word count in this case?

My keyword output looks like

```
 stats stats main
 scoring standard
 poems life index  htm
 stats stats main
 view htm
 tech hub tag list
 players playerpage        
 gadanie 
 standings overall

 tech hub tag
 stats stats main
 poems life         htm
 board     tito headquarters
 thread       tip islands party
 thread       illustrious house improving wordiness
 view htm
 listeperson php
 listeperson php
```

Comment: please provide your current output

Comment: http://03cubsml.baseball.cbssports.com/stats/stats-main?selectedplayer=2122997    statsstatsmain

Comment: split generates ARRAY, not space separated array.

Comment: Yeah I understand . But my keywords output looks like

 stats stats main
 scoring standard
 poems life index  htm
 stats stats main
 view htm
 tech hub tag list
 players playerpage        
 gadanie 
 standings overall

 tech hub tag
 stats stats main
 poems life         htm
 board     tito headquarters
 thread       tip islands party
 thread       illustrious house improving wordiness
 view htm
 listeperson php
 listeperson php

Comment: maybe your tool displays them in such way. Split returns  ARRAY. Apply size directly to it

Comment: I tried size(keywords), the output seems a bit diff. May be its because of tabs or spaces. The first row has keywrods stats stats main and the array size is returned as 4. Similarly row 7 has keywords players playerpage but the size of array comes as 11.